# How to upload this photo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to use both of the objective c methods listed below in my application. The first method uploads a `UIImagePicker` photograph to a local server.

```
// I would still like to use this method structure but with the `AVCam` classes.
-(void)uploadPhoto {
//upload the image and the title to the web service
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"upload", @"command", UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo.image,70), @"file", fldTitle.text, @"title", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //completion
    if (![json objectForKey:@"error"]) {
        //success
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your photo is uploaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yay!" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

    } else {
        //error, check for expired session and if so - authorize the user
        NSString* errorMsg = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
        [UIAlertView error:errorMsg];
        if ([@"Authorization required" compare:errorMsg]==NSOrderedSame) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];
        }
    }
}];
}
```

I want to add a second method : The second method performs an `IBAction` picture snap using `AVCam` but I changed it to void to launch the the view loads using `[self snapStillImage]`.

***EDIT***

```
- (IBAction)snapStillImage:(id)sender
{
dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
    // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
    [[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];
    // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
    [ViewController5 setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
    // Capture a still image.
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
        //
          photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        }
    }];
});
}
```

Can someone please set `photo` via `AVCam`? At the very least humor me and start a dialogue about `AVFoundation` and its appropriate classes for tackling an issue like this.

Additional info: The avcam method is simply an excerpt from this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

@Aksh1t I want to set an `UIImage` named image with the original contents of the `AVFoundation` snap. Not `UIImagePicker`. Here is the method that sets the outlet using `UIImagePicker`.

```
#pragma mark - Image picker delegate methods
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
// Resize the image from the camera
UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
// Crop the image to a square (yikes, fancy!)
UIImage *croppedImage = [scaledImage croppedImage:CGRectMake((scaledImage.size.width -photo.frame.size.width)/2, (scaledImage.size.height -photo.frame.size.height)/2, photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height)];
// Show the photo on the screen
photo.image = croppedImage;
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

After that I simply want to upload it using the first method I posted. Sorry for being unclear. I basically want to do this in my new app (i was unclear about what app).

1. Take a photo using `AVCam`
2. Set that photo to an `UIImageView` `IBOutlet` named photo
3. Upload photo (the original `AVCam` photo) to the server

The basic framework is above and I will answer any questions

Comment: It does not seem very clear to me what you want to do. Please elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to set `UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];` but with AVCam. I will update my question with the method that does that in the original application (link I posted)

Comment: Okay. If you are following AVCam's style, you should not have set the return type of `snapStillImage` to void, because that method is meant to be triggered from within the camera controller. Why do you call it during view load?

Comment: I have it set up to snap a picture when the view loads. just part of the apps functionality.

Comment: Okay, so what happens during your current setup? When the `snapStillImage` is called, does some crash or error occur or does it work fine, but without taking the image snap? Also, have you initialized the `stillImageOutput` correctly, like in the AVCam demo?

Comment: When it is called in my app it takes a picture and saves it to my pictures on my iPad. Now I just want to set that picture to an UIImageView IBOutlet named photo and upload photo to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code in your `snapStillImage` method takes a photo into the `imageData` variable.

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
```

Next, you are creating one `UIImage` object from this data like this

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Instead of the above code, make a global variable `UIImage *photo;`, and initialize that with the `imageData` when your `snapStillImage` takes the photo like this

```
photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Since `photo` is a global variable, you will then be able to use that in your `uploadPhoto` method and send it to your server.

Hope this helps, and if you have any question, leave it in the comments.

---

*Edit:*

Since you already have a `IBOutlet UIImageView *photo;` in your file, you don't even need a global variable to store the `UIImage`. You can just replace the following line in your `snapStillImage` method:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

with this line

```
photo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: should i set up a new method entirely with the messages you posted? I think ill figure it out before the nights done. I greatly appreciate your help either way and will accept your answer asap if it works

Comment: No, you just need to make one global `UIImage` variable, and edit one line in your  `snapStillImage` method which I have written.

Comment: To be clear you're saying simply add photo = ... To the snapStillImage method after making photo a global variable?

Comment: Yes. Since the photo is already being taken and saved in your album, all you need is a reference to that `UIImage` so that you can access it in your upload method.

Comment: When I add that line photo=... Under the other stuff in snapStillImage I get an error. Where do I set the global variable? The native app had photo set to a iboutlet  uiimage view named photo...suggestions?

Comment: You should add a global variable `UIImage *photo;` in the .h file.

Comment: If you still have the `IBOutlet UIImageView` named `photo`, then you don't even need to make a global variable. Editing my answer to reflect this in a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71662/discussion-between-program1-and-aksh1t).